# Correct proof of $\det(X+iY) \det(X-iY)>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can someone please look over my proof below as to why $\det(X+iY) \det(X-iY)>0$ for real matrices $X,Y$, such that $\det(X+iY)$, $ \det(X-iY)$  not both the zero, and tell me if it's correct ?

My original idea was that $\det(X-iY)=\det(\overline{X+iY})=\overline{\det(X+iY)}$ (where the overline, when applied to a matrix,  denotes pointwise conjugation of the elements of the matrix), so $\det(X+iY) \det(X-iY)= \det(X+iY) \overline{\det(X+iY)}$, which is $>0$, since for any nonzero complex number $w$, we have that $w\overline{w}>0$.

Comment: But $\det(X+iY)$ can be zero even if $X+iY$ is not a zero matrix. For example, if $\det X = 0$ and $Y = X$.

Comment: @Litho Ok, I've modified the assumption and assumed that  $\det(X+iY)$, $ \det(X-iY)$  are not both the zero. Is my proof then correct ?

Comment: In this case, yes. Though you might add to the proof that since these numbers are complex conjugate, "not both of them are zero" is equivalent to "neither of them is zero". I mean, you say that $\det(X+iY)\overline{\det(X+iY)}>0$ since for every non-zero $w$, $w\overline{w}>0$. But you did not assume that $\det(X+iY)\neq 0$, you only assumed that at least one of the numbers $\det(X+iY)$, $\det(X-iY)$ is non-zero; what if $\det(X+iY)=0$ and $\det(X-iY)\neq 0$? But, of course, this is impossible since these numbers are complex conjugate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof is good. The determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix can be written
$$
\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}
(\operatorname{sgn}\sigma)
a_{1,\sigma(1)}a_{2,\sigma(2)}\dots a_{n,\sigma(n)}
$$
and conjugating each coefficient gives the conjugate.

Another way for seeing this is to write the matrix as
$$
A=PLU
$$
where $P$ is a permutation matrix (which has real coefficients), $L$ is lower triangular and invertible, and $U$ is upper triangular (with either $1$ or $0$ along the diagonal); thus
$\det P=\det\bar{P}=\pm1$ and
$$
\det U=\det\bar{U}=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $A$ is not invertible}\\
1 & \text{if $A$ is invertible}
\end{cases}
$$
So, in case $A$ is invertible, $\det A=\det L$ and $\det\bar{A}=\det\bar{L}$, but the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the coefficients on the diagonal. Thus $\det\bar{L}=\overline{\det L}$ and $\det \bar{A}=\overline{\det A}$ follows.